# Java JList and JTextArea

Tags: jlist

I am stuck on a java project.
I am working with TXT files, and i have the open these TXT files from the JList.
Since i am a total noob at this, it took me a few hours to manage to make the JList work. But now i am stuck at the JTextArea.
The idea is this: clicking on a item from the JList (item = a TXT file from a folder), it should open that TXT file in the JTextArea to view it.

..here is my code so far ..it's a bit long:

-JButton for the search and putting the TXT files in the JList:

```
            JButton searchSearchButton = new JButton("Search");
            searchSearchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    

                    DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();

                    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Zoli\\Desktop\\New folder");
                    File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                            return name.startsWith(searchKeywordTextField.getText()) && name.endsWith(".txt");
                        }                       
                    });

                    for(File f : matches){
                        model1.addElement(f.getName());
                    }

                    searchList.setModel(model1);                    
                }
            });
            searchSearchButton.setBounds(186, 43, 89, 23);
            linuxSearchPane.add(searchSearchButton);
```

-This is the JTextArea and the JList code:

```
            final JTextArea searchTextArea = new JTextArea();
            JScrollPane searchTextAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(searchTextArea);
            searchTextAreaScrollPane.setBounds(316, 43, 496, 430);
            linuxSearchPane.add(searchTextAreaScrollPane);

            final JList searchList = new JList();
            searchList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            searchList.setVisibleRowCount(20);
            searchList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {               
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    searchTextArea.setText("");

                    for(Object o : searchList.getSelectedValuesList()){
                        searchTextArea.append(o.toString()+"\r\n");

                    }

                }
            });
```

-All i managed to do is, when i select an item from the JList, it prints out the item name in the JTextArea not what it contains in the TXT.
Here is a picture to show you:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X26Jq.jpg)

could anyone please help me with this...i have zero idea...i have read about JList, and JTextArea, but nothing even points to what i need...

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT!!!
Here's the code:

```
            final JTextArea searchTextArea = new JTextArea();
            JScrollPane searchTextAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(searchTextArea);
            searchTextAreaScrollPane.setBounds(316, 43, 496, 430);
            linuxSearchPane.add(searchTextAreaScrollPane);

            final JList searchList = new JList();
            searchList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            searchList.setVisibleRowCount(20);
            searchList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {               
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    searchTextArea.setText("");
                    String root = "C:\\Users\\Zoli\\Desktop\\New folder\\";
                    String filename;
                    String lineRead = "";
                    String fileContent = "";

                    try {                       
                        for(Object o : searchList.getSelectedValuesList()){
                            filename = o.toString();    
                            FileReader reader = new FileReader(root + filename);
                            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);

                            while(lineRead != null){
                                try {
                                    lineRead = buffer.readLine();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                if(lineRead != null){
                                    fileContent = fileContent + lineRead + "\r\n";
                                    searchTextArea.setText(fileContent);
                                }
                            }


                        }

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });
```

Also here's the picture to see how it works: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH08I.jpg)